# Should I put world in plural or not, in this context?

Tags: grammar

Which of these 2 sentences is grammatically correct?

1. If you are coming from the A or the B world
2. If you are coming from the A or the B world**s**

(world vs world**s**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of them could be correct depending on what A and B refer to.

If A is one world and B is another world then (1) would be correct.

If A is a set of worlds or B is a set of worlds then (2) would be correct.

---

I can't find a link for exactly this question, but [here's a description](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/or) of how verbs are treated with the "or" conjunction:

> When we connect two or more nouns using or, we use a singular verb with singular nouns, and a plural verb with plural countable nouns:
>
> A banjo or a mandolin is what we need. (singular nouns)
>
> I think more pictures or ornaments are needed in this room. (plural nouns)